# WCF RIA Authorization based on query method parameters

Tags: authorization, wcf-ria-services

Lets say we have a method below.

How would you implement auhorization that would allow execution if current user is a member of that project team and deny if she is not?

public Project GetProject(Guid projectID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just authorize imperatively in the query.

```
if (!IsUserAMemberOfTheProject(this.ServiceContext.User.Identity.Name, projectID)
{
  throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("...");
}
```

It will get merged into the pipeline correctly as a 403.